# Fetching Minimum/Maximum for each group in ActiveRecord

Tags: activerecord, group-by, aggregate-functions, minimum

This is an age-old question where given a table with attributes 'type', 'variety' and 'price', that you fetch the record with the minimum price for each type there is.

In SQL, we can do [this](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) by:

```
select f.type, f.variety, f.price   
from (  select type, min(price) as minprice from table group by type ) as x  
inner join table as f on f.type = x.type and f.price = x.minprice;`
```

We could perhaps imitate this by:

```
minprices = Table.minimum(:price, :group => type)  
result = []
minprices.each_pair do |t, p|  
   result << Table.find(:first, :conditions => ["type = ? and price = ?", t, p])
end
```

Is there a better implementation than this?

Comment: how to get maximum and minimum price for each type ??

Answer (score 12):

```
Table.minimum(:price, :group => :type)
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-minimum for more.

Comment: how to get maximum and minimum price for each type ??

Comment: For some reason the `:group => :type` part is being ignored, for me.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
Table.group(:type).minimum(:price)
```

And it returns an object like this.

```
{
 "type1"=>500.0,
 "type2"=>200.0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use #[`find_by_sql`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001302), but this implies returning a model object, which might not be what you want.

If you want to go bare to the metal, you can also use #[`select_values`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#M001063):

```
data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_values("
        SELECT f.type, f.variety, f.price
        FROM (SELECT type, MIN(price) AS minprice FROM table GROUP BY type ) AS x
        INNER JOIN table AS f ON f.type = x.type AND f.price = x.minprice")
puts data.inspect
[["type", "variety", 0.00]]
```

ActiveRecord is just a tool.  You use it when it's convenient.  When SQL does a better job, you use that.

Answer (score 1):

I've been fighting with this for a while and for the moment it seems that you are pretty much stuck with generating SQL.

However, I have a couple refinements to offer.

Instead of `find_by_sql`, as @François suggested, I've used ActiveRecord's `to_sql` and `joins` to "guide" my SQL a little bit:

```
subquery_sql = Table.select(["MIN(price) as price", :type]).group(:type).to_sql
joins_sql    = "INNER JOIN (#{subquery_sql}) as S
                ON table.type = S.type
                AND table.price = S.price"

Table.joins(joins_sql).where(<other conditions>).order(<your order>)
```

As you can see, I'm still using raw SQL, but at least it's only on the part where AR gives no support (AFAIK ActiveRecord simply can't manage `INNER JOIN ... ON ...`) and not on the whole thing.

Using `joins` instead of find_by_sql makes the query chainable - you can add extra conditions, or sort the table, or put everything in a scope.

Answer (score 0):

While this question is pretty stale, I was asking the same question today.
Here's a gist of a solution to compose the SQL needed to accomplish the goal with minimal (2) queries.

Please lmk if there are better ways these days!

Using `Security` and `Price` models, where Securities have many (historical) Prices, and you are after the Securities' most recent price:

```
module MostRecentBy
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.scope :most_recent_by, ->(group_by_col, max_by_col) {
      from(
        <<~SQL
          (
            SELECT #{table_name}.*
            FROM #{table_name} JOIN (
               SELECT #{group_by_col}, MAX(#{max_by_col}) AS #{max_by_col}
               FROM #{table_name}
               GROUP BY #{group_by_col}
            ) latest
            ON #{table_name}.date = latest.#{max_by_col}
            AND #{table_name}.#{group_by_col} = latest.#{group_by_col}
          ) #{table_name}
        SQL
      )
    }
  end
end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MostRecentBy

  belongs_to :security

  scope :most_recent_by_security, -> { most_recent_by(:security_id, :date) }
end

class Security < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices
  has_one :latest_price, 
    -> { Price.most_recent_by_security },
    class_name: 'Price'
end
```

now you can call the following in your controller code:

```
def index
  @resources = Security.all.includes(:latest_price)

  render json: @resources.as_json(include: :latest_price)
end
```

which results in two queries:

```
  Security Load (4.4ms)  SELECT "securities".* FROM "securities"
  Price Load (140.3ms)  SELECT "prices".* FROM (
    SELECT prices.*
    FROM prices JOIN (
       SELECT security_id, MAX(date) AS date
       FROM prices
       GROUP BY security_id
    ) latest
    ON prices.date = latest.date
    AND prices.security_id = latest.security_id
  ) prices
  WHERE "prices"."price_type" = $1 AND "prices"."security_id" IN (...)
```

for reference: https://gist.github.com/pmn4/eb58b036cc78fb41a36c56bcd6189d68

Answer (score -1):

To update Avdi's answer above:

> Table.minimum(:price, :group => :type)

Here is the updated URL:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-minimum

Comment: Perhaps a link to a more up-to-date version of Rails would be helpful.  Not sure why you chose to link to 2 major versions ago.

Comment: Thanks Isaac. Updated.