# How do I select the max child value in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm not even sure how to word this, so an example:

I have two models,

```
Chicken   
  id   
  name

EggCounterReadings
  id   
  chicken_id   
  value_on_counter
  timestamp
```

I don't always record a count for every chicken when I do counts.

*Using ActiveRecord* how do I get the latest egg count per chicken?

So if I have 1 chicken and 3 counts, the counts would be 1 today, 15 tomorrow, and 18 the next day. That chicken has laid 18 eggs, not 34

**UPDATE**: Found exactly what I was trying to do in MySQL. Find "[The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)". So I need to `.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM EggCounterReadings WHERE <conditions> ORDER BY timestamp DESC) GROUP BY chicken_id")`

Comment: This is VASTLY simplified, but it's the best I could do to explain what I'm looking for.

Comment: Almost duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185569/fetching-minimum-maximum-for-each-group-in-activerecord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your updated question, I've changed my answer.

```
chicken = Chicken.first
count = chicken.egg_counter_readings.last.value_on_counter
```

If you don't want the latest record, but the largest egg yield, then try this:

```
chicken = Chicken.first
count = chicken.egg_counter_readings.maximum(value_on_counter)
```

I believe that should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I do however record more than 1 item per entry. Think of it this way, chickens are happily laying eggs all day, a counter below them. I come along and read the counter for each chicken and write that number down. Perhaps I could rename the second model to LayedEggCount.

Comment: That looks good. Perhaps I'm trying to over optimize before I have a problem. But I'll have lots of chickens to iterate over later. Is there any way to get a collection of the max egg counter readings grouped by chicken?  What I would do in SQL is SELECT MAX(value_on_counter) as value_on_counter, id, rest,of,fields group by chicken_id.

Comment: And with that I think I have my answer:  
EggCounterReadings.find_by_sql("insert awesome statement from above"). Accepted answer as that's 98% of what I needed!

Comment: A more ActiveRecord-ish approach might look more like this: `EggCounterReading.maximum(value_on_counter, :group => :chicken)`.  But find_by_sql will most likely be faster.